# NoSuchElementException in c# for google search box using selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate a simple search using selenium webdriver. My code is to launch the google.co.uk page in IE, wait until the search box has appeared, locate the search box and input "compare the market". However I keep getting a NoSuchElementException from the application, even though I can see it on the page.

My code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string searchEngine = "www.google.co.uk";
        IWebDriver IEbrowser = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Drivers");
        IEbrowser.Url = searchEngine;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(IEbrowser, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25));
        IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
        {
            return d.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        });
        
        var searchBox = IEbrowser.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
        searchBox.SendKeys("compare the market");
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to find element with name == q

HTML info of the search box:

I get the same error message if I try to use any of the other page element locators like Id. But this only appears to error out using the google search page.

Comment: Sorry, HTML info: <input name="q" title="Search" class="gsfi" id="lst-ib" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="false"

Comment: You should edit your question and add the HTML info from your comment. It will more likely be seen in the question and a lot easier to read when properly formatted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've kinda overengineered this task. :) The code below works fine.

```
string searchEngine = "www.google.co.uk";
IWebDriver IEbrowser = InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Drivers");
IEbrowser.Navigate().GoToUrl(searchEngine);
IEbrowser.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("compare the market");
```

If you want to wait for an element, there is a simpler way to do this using [`ExpectedConditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm). See an example below. Read the linked docs to see the other available conditions that can be used.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(IEbrowser, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Name("q")));
```

Comment: Hi jeff, did you try running this code? and did it work for you? I am still getting the same error message back, when I add the wait condition the app waits for 25 seconds and then gives me a timeout error.

Comment: I ran it using the Firefox driver and it worked fine. I don't have the IE driver installed. Is everything up to date? Have you tried with the Firefox driver?

Comment: Yes it'll work with firefox but not with the IE driver